# ASP.Net Core: URL Rewriting Middleware in C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

I'm trying to write the following url rewrite XMl in C#, but I'm struggling to know what goes where. Here is the exisitng working XML:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- BEGIN RULE TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
    <rule name="Force HTTPS and non-WWW only" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://mycustomdomain.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <!-- END RULE TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

What I've tried so far in c#:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("^(.*)$", "https://mycustomdomain.com/$1")
    .AddRedirect(@"^www\.", "https://mycustomdomain.com/$1")
    .AddRedirectToHttps(301);

app.UseRewriter(options);
```

I'm pretty sure the redirect to HTTPS works correct, but I'm not sure of the syntax in the redirect as well as the non-www.

**[UPDATE]**
So I tried the above code, but I receive:

```
::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Anything? Anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check With teleriks Fiddler and investigate request and response